# setting must be in the form "name=value" in vs 2017

Tags: azure

I have been learning the bot framework from microsoft and have been following a tutorial on pluralsight. I have made the changes to my `Global.asax.cs` and for some reason I keep on getting the error `setting must be in the form name=value`. I have no idea what to do and how to get rid of these errors. Any help would be highly appreciated.

`Global.asax.cs`

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {

        // This code chunk below will allow us to use table bot data store instead of 
        // in memory data store 
        Conversation.UpdateContainer(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
                // here we grab the storage container string from our web config and connecting
                var store = new TableBotDataStore(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                builder.Register(c => store).
                Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore).
                AsSelf().
                SingleInstance();
            });



        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TableBotDataStore is for Azure Table Storage, and it seems you are using some sql connectionstring. You would usually have that connection string in the AppSettings section, not the ConnectionStrings section (yes, the names are a bit misguiding here).